# Multiple traverse via same edge collection in ArangoDB 2.8

Tags: graph, traversal, arangodb, aql

Have one edge collection for Product->Model->Brand graphs

```
FOR m IN INBOUND "BrandModel/49798592791" BrandModelLink
   FOR p IN INBOUND m._id BrandModelLink
RETURN { model: m, product: p }
```

Result - empty. Its restriction forever or beta period?

Now I use selfmake combination like

```
FOR m IN INBOUND "BrandModel/49798592791" BrandModelLink
   FOR plink IN BrandModelLink
      FILTER plink._to == m._id
      FOR p IN Product 
         FILTER p._id == plink._from
RETURN { model: m, product: p }
```

Hope the first option will work in the final version.

P.S. Simplify AQL traverse its just powerful and amazing feature!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there should be no restriction about using the same collection in multiple traverse statements, neither in beta nor after.

It seems to be an issue with the `_id` to continue traversing.
This is a bug in beta and will be fixed for 2.8 final.

For now could you simply try to remove the `_id` in the second filter statement:

```
FOR m IN INBOUND "BrandModel/49798592791" BrandModelLink
   FOR p IN INBOUND m BrandModelLink
RETURN { model: m, product: p }
```

It is possible to use a complete document (vertex) as starting point for traversal as well.